# SpagoBI: Adding external hyperlink to report

Tags: birt, spagobi

I am building a report in SpagoBI using birt. I have build the report but I wanted to add a hyperlink that will point to an external site. I am unable to figure out how to do it.

Any help is highly apprciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Perform below steps:**

1. Open your BIRT report in SpagoBI studio (eclipse)
2. Click on the data element of table
3. Select property window which is situated at bottom of studio
4. Select hyperlink tab. Click on Edit
5. To add custom URI. Select URI from dropdown. Click on fx (javascript syntax)
6. Add URI in javascript format - "http://www.example.com/"+row["id"]. Here id is column value to be passed

[Click here to check sample property window editor view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCGza.png)